# iOS7 Safari change webkit-overflow-scrolling background color

Tags: css, ios7, safari, webkit

In a Cordova iPad App for iOS7, I have a DIV (.scrollContainer) with fixed height into which I'm putting some much taller content, and I'm allowing that contained content to scroll like this:

```
.scrollContainer
{
    width: 512px;
    height: 546px;
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll !important;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    background-color: #fff !important;
}

#content
{
    width: 512px;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

The user can scroll the nested content nicely in the touch interface, but the user can also scroll 'past' the end of the content above or below as per the iOS 7 interface (i.e. it snaps back when they let go).

The background colour revealed as they over-scroll is **black**. Is there any way to set this to a different colour using CSS?

Comment: I'm looking for a similar solution on mac desktop. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22477729/css-style-window-background-beyond-page-on-mac-possible i guess it should be possible to mimic the behaviour with javascript and the scrollhandler.

Answer (score 14):

Faced the same problem today (iOS 7.1), seems like a glitch or something,

Adding borders or padding seems to fix it, allowing you to set a background color for the element itself. I sorted it out with this trick:

```
padding-top:1px;
margin-top:-1px;
```

Another solution would be to leave background unset on .scrollContainer element, and set it for its parent.

Comment: This fix works perfectly. Would personally recommend going for the 2nd mentioned solution: Only set background color on a non-scrolling container - way cleaner that way. Thanks!

Comment: This is a wonderful fix! the second solution is really the way to go, great job!

Comment: After much research, came across this. My savior!