# CSS Style window background beyond page on Mac possible?

Tags: css, macos, browser

Is it possible to style or color the window pane background of the browser?
When scrolling beyond the edge in Chrome and Safari on Mac,
the whole page is pulled a bit down and/or sideways.

It shows a basic canvas style of texture,
is it possible to style that region (with CSS) ?

**Edit:** i found a (crude) way to prevent the overscrolling entirely,
but i'm looking for a way to set a color or texture, to match the overall design.
[Prevent "overscrolling" of web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12046315/prevent-overscolling-of-web-page)

[image: Scroll beyond page edge]

Comment: Does this help? http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/47125

Comment: That is rather permanent, lol. I hoped to find a solution for websites, to be able to set it to a color or texture, matching the overall design.

Comment: Well, I'm not a MAC user, but I think this things are related to the Browsers themselves, in this case Safari. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 17):

probably this is not needed anymore but maybe someone else wants to do the same :D

this should put a background-color on the overscroll-area of any ios device

```
body:after {
    content: '';
    position: fixed;
    top: -50%;
    right: -50%;
    bottom: -50%;
    left: -50%;
    z-index: -1;
    background: #000000;
}
```

[here](https://gist.github.com/puresamari/037f486166953b5a7b95d96ad925e645) is the link to my gist

Comment: In my brief (desktop) testing: this is needed still on Safari. Chrome, however, works with a `background-color` set on `body`. Firefox seems to be a bit smarter and uses whatever background is currently in front. (Neither the Safari or the Chrome approach above work for Firefox.)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is not possible. This is part of the application (Safari) and can not be styled with webpages.

Comment: The overscroll area is now the same color as the body's background color in both Safari and Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Set the body colour `body {background-color: white}` should work.

More complex, if you need to change the overscroll colour, while leaving the body colour white (only tested on iOS10.3 Safari). I did the following using a 1x1 white pixel:

```
body {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    background-image: url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP7//wAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

FYI 1: three other things I tried that didn't work for me were: `outline: 100px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);`, `box-shadow: 0 0 0 100px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);`, and `background: #FFF, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);`.

FYI 2: I recall that really old versions of Safari needed the colour set on the html element.

Answer (score 1):

You can now do this with a meta tag:

```
<meta name="theme-color" content="#923941">
```