# IOS Safari: How to change background color of footer and header which is out of <body> bounds (refresh / bottom) area)

Tags: html, css, mobile-safari

So, even with background color set like this:

```
body, html {
     background: #000;
}
```

When I scroll to the bottom of the page on IOS Safari, there is this "elastic part" which reveals a white background which is not part of the design of my website. Similar thing happens on header of the page when I try to refresh:
[image]

It has been fixed on CNN.com, but I can't figure out how.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37717756/is-there-a-way-to-style-the-ios-safari-overscroll-elastic-scroll-area), you could try the following:

```
<meta name="theme-color" content="#f6f8fa" media="(prefers-color-scheme: light)">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#161b22" media="(prefers-color-scheme: dark)">
```

Comment: I will accept this answer, but leave my question up as it is better worded than the one you referenced. Also With this I can only change  header and footer both. However ideally I would like to change them separately.

Comment: I think changing them independently is not possible, but I'm not entirely sure.